# Isolate a failed SSD drive

Tags: raid, hard-drive, ssd, drive-failure

I have recently had a Samsung 840 Pro 256 GB SSD fail on our server. The drive was configured in a RAID 1 array and a reboot was sufficient to bring things back online.

When looking at the Intel Rapid Storage dashboard I now have the following output:

[image]

The problem I am having is isolating the faulty disk from the 4 physical drives in the server. I expected an orange warning light on the drive bay, but they're all solid green. Intel Rapid Storage does display the drive serial number, which in hindsight should have been labelled on the drive itself.

[image]

Is there any way to determine which of these drives has failed without pulling out the server or using some form of trial and error?

Comment: Check your eventlog. If lucky the serial number will be show, but that depend on the array driver/management pack you have. With a s/n in hand, you will surelly need to open the server case to identify it

Comment: Fortunately Intel Rapid Storage shows me the serial number, unfortunately these weren't printed onto the drive bays. I'm trying to find a way to isolate the failed drive without powering down and unscrewing the disks to examine the serial numbers on each one. There's an option to "Activate LED" on the dashboard but this doesn't seem to work with these drives.

Comment: I suspect it's more that the warning lights don't work with Intel Rapid Storage (which is essentially fakeraid) and that a real hardware RAID would have been fine.

Comment: Supermicro-life... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Rapid Storage UI shows you the port each disk is on.
That should make it pretty simple to see which one is bad.

Detailing: if you click each disk, it will show port 0,1,2 and 3.
That should correspond to 1,2,3 and 4 as installed in your server.

So if the disk in port 1 is down in Intel RS UI, it should mean that the disk physically marked as 2 is down on your server. Judging by your screen-shot that's actually the one.

Also, the newer version of the Intel RS UI has also an option to 'activate the LED' of your selected drive. That would make things 100% clear.